# Results of a query in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to know where I can retrieve the result of a query in Codeigniter.

The code:

```
$this->db->where('usuario', $this->input->post('drcorreo')); 
$cdb=$this->db->get('usuarios');
```

What I want is where is saved the name of the user in this query in order to save it in the session class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
### saving in the session ###
$rs = $this->db->where('usuario', $this->input->post('drcorreo'))->get('usuarios');
if($rs->num_rows() > 0){
    $data   = $rs->row_array();     #for a single tuple use result_array() for multiple tuples
    $this->session->set_userdata('usuario', $data['usuario']);  #saving it in session
}

### to retrieve dfrom the session ###
$usuario    = $this->session->userdata('usuario');
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. When I try to retrieve the username I watch vale and the name must be alexander. What's wrong?

Comment: First echo your query and run it in your phpmyadmin. To echo the query: `echo $this->db->last_qeury();`. Second, print your `$data` array and see if you are fetching the correct result from the db. Third, print the session `print_r($this->session->all_userdata());`.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I can watch the username and I can save it in the session table. The problem was that the query I typed was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$result = $this->db->get_where($table, array('username' =>$this->input->post('drcorreo'))); 
$result->result_array();
```

for documentation you may read it in here [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)